# unnamed parameter as argument in a called function

Tags: kotlin, variables, parameters, return, arguments

can a var that is not named in the param be used as an arg when a function is called in the main? like in the following codes:

```
fun main() {
    val firstNumber = 10
    val secondNumber = 5
    val thirdNumber = 8
    
    val result = add(firstNumber, secondNumber)
    val anotherResult = subtract(firstNumber, thirdNumber)

    println("$firstNumber + $secondNumber = $result")
    println("$firstNumber - $thirdNumber = $anotherResult")
}

fun add(firstNumber: Int, secondNumber: Int): Int {
    return firstNumber + secondNumber
}

fun subtract(firstNumber: Int, secondNumber: Int): Int {
    return firstNumber - secondNumber
}
```

thirdNumber is not a parameter in the two functions i.e add and subtract functions but was used as an argument in variable anotherResult().

i have run the code and i expect the code not to run but it runs

Answer (score 0):

> can a var that is not named in the param be used as an arg when a function is called in the main?

Yes, that is how variable and parameters work, at least in Kotlin.

Variables are just a way to give names to values, so you can refer to those values, reuse them, and understand their meaning better. They don't have to match the names of the parameters of the function you're calling.

You could make things even clearer by using named parameters, to show that you are using the value of an arbitrarily named variable as argument for a parameter of a different name:

```kotlin
val anotherResult = subtract(firstNumber = firstNumber, secondNumber = thirdNumber)
```

> i have run the code and i expect the code not to run but it runs

Wouldn't you expect `add(1, 2)` to work? Those literal arguments don't have names, so they can't match the parameter names.